# Get an array from URL

Tags: php

I have a URL in this format:

https://www.example.com/page?=item1&item2&item3&item4&item5

I need to put each item into a variable, likes this:

```
$var1 = item1;
$var2 = item2;
$var3 = item3;
$var4 = item4;
$var5 = item5;
```

It does not actually say item1, item2 etc in the URL, their actual values are different every time.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need to do with the parameters? You can use `parse_url()`

Comment: We can do this, however, why would you want? Especially why do you want single variables? There should be more information about your intention. Btw. your URL is malformed

Comment: Where does the URL come from? This question needs to be improved. It is in multiple ways ambiguous. - e.g. *"Get an array" / "need to put each item into a variable"*

Answer (score 2):

## The URL Query String / GET-Parameters

Your example URL `https://www.example.com/page?=item1&item2&item3&item4&item5` is malformed. The query string starting after the question mark `?` is parsed with the format:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2...
```

Your URL means:

```
<empty name> = item1
item2        = ''
item3        = ''
...
```

Empty names are ignored when PHP parses GET-parameters.

Let's assume you have an URL `https://www.example.com/page?item1&item2&item3&item4&item5` instead. (Note the remove `=`.)

## Accessing GET-Parameters

If the given URL is the one of you PHP current script, you can easily access the GET-parameter using the preinitialized global variable `$_GET`. Try `var_dump($_GET)` and you get:

```
array (size=5)
  'item1' => string '' (length=0)
  'item2' => string '' (length=0)
  'item3' => string '' (length=0)
  'item4' => string '' (length=0)
  'item5' => string '' (length=0)
```

As you can see, `item1`...`item5` are the keys of the associative array, each with an empty string `''` as the default value since you did not set any by `item1=the+item`.

## Get The Keys as Array

To get closer to your needs specified in the title of your question, you can extract the keys using `array_keys`:

```
$url_keys = array_keys($_GET);
```

Now you have an array like this:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'item1' (length=5)
  1 => string 'item2' (length=5)
  2 => string 'item3' (length=5)
  3 => string 'item4' (length=5)
  4 => string 'item5' (length=5)
```

## Extracting as Variables

I do not recommend to extract any changing data structures into your variable scope. Be aware that the client could even manipulate the request sending you something you do not expect. It is hard to find variable names when you do not exactly know what you get. Prefer to operate on arrays.

However, if you really need to import the keys into your variables scope, here are the ways how you can achieve that. PHP does provide a function `extract` that can do that in several ways. We want to use the numeric indexes with a prefix to become the variable names:

```
extract(array_keys($_GET), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'var');
```

The result will be:

```
$var_0 = item1,
$var_1 = item2
```

The zero-based numbering is due to the fact, that arrays are nubered zero-based by default, so the returned array from the function `array_keys`.

To get the numbering as illustrated in your question, you can also renumber the array of keys.

```
extract(array_combine(range(1, count($_GET)),array_keys($_GET)), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'var');
```

If you are bothered by the underscore within the names, you can also extract the keys using dynamic variable creation in a fairly simple loop:

```
foreach (array_keys($_GET) as $k => $v)
  ${'var'. ($k+1)} = $v;
```

When you want global variables instead, use

```
foreach (array_keys($_GET) as $k => $v)
  $GLOBALS['var'. ($k+1)] = $v;
```

## Extract Keys from Arbitrary URL

If you have to analyze a URL string from somewhere, you can use the `parse_url` function to extract the query first and then use `parse_str` which parses a query in the same way as PHP does automatically with the script's URL when building the `$_GET` associative array on startup.

```
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
```

`$params` is now

```
array (size=5)
  'item1' => string '' (length=0)
  'item2' => string '' (length=0)
  'item3' => string '' (length=0)
  'item4' => string '' (length=0)
  'item5' => string '' (length=0)
```

You can handle that in the same way as shown above with the `$_GET` array.

Comment: That's a very nice answer. Congratulations !

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
$var1 = $_GET['item1'];
$var2 = $_GET['item2'];
$var3 = $_GET['item3'];
$var4 = $_GET['item4'];
$var5 = $_GET['item5'];
```

All your URL variables are stored in the GET array

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your URL format...

However, as already answered here, you can extract each parameter (if specified by name) using `$_GET['item1']` etc...

And, if there some other format or Unknown number of values, you can work over the whole URL by getting it using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which will give the string:

```
/page?=item1&item2&item3&item4&item5
```

then, splitting that string with seperator `&`, assuming every splitted substring is a value of an item in the array (?) in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you want to get all parameters in your URL.

Actually, $_GET is already an array that you also can use. But when you want to create your own array / variable list, that is also possible.

To do that, you can use the super global `$_GET`, this is an array with every URL parameter in it.

For example, I made this code for you

```
<?php
$return = [];
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $return[$key] = $value;
}
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($return);
?>
```

When I visit the page (http://example.com/temp.php?a&b), it will result in

> array(2) { ["a"]=> string(0) "" ["b"]=> string(0) "" } array(2) { ["a"]=> string(0) "" ["b"]=> string(0) "" }

As you can see, this has the same data. And, because you say that the values and maybe also the keys (file.php?key=value) can be diffrent, I recommend you to use the array.

So, you can also save them in formats like JSON, to easilly save the in the database, so you can use the afterwards.

When I use `json_encode` on one of the arrays it gives me a string that you can use.

> {"a":"","b":""}

With `json_decode` you can change it back to the array